# remount /mnt as read-write

Tags: file-system, mount, file-permissions

I am getting error "Read-only filesystem" when trying to add a new directory in /mnt via Terminal Emulator. So, I tried :

```
su
busybox mount -o remount,rw /mnt
```

in order to remount filesystem for /mnt as read-write; but I am getting error "can't find /mnt in /proc/mounts".

What is this error for !?

PS. My ultimate aim is to then mount an external storage on that new directory; say /mnt/myextdrive

Comment: Doesn't your device have a directory named usbotg under mnt? Why not mount it there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use these commands

```
su -c 'busybox mount -o remount,rw /'    # this will remount rootfs at / in rw mode
su -c 'mkdir /mnt/"NEW_DIR"'             # replace NEW_DIR with the name of the directory you aim to create under /mnt
```

Note that in Android `/mnt` is not a mount point for any real or pseudo-filesystem but its sub-directories are (actually, `/mnt` is a sub-directory of the `/` (rootFS), which is why you'd have to remount that to apply changes here). Also note that mnt directory in Android is created by kernel at every boot<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>  so any modification would be lost after shutdown.

---

<sub>1: mnt doesn't exist in a persistent filesystem but in a specific ramfs named [rootfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt) - a filesystem which exists in RAM only.</sub>